# Flutter Stepper on ListView

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have question,
I have a Stepper in the listView but it can't even be scolled, I tried it for three days, but there was no result, why did this happen and how to solve it?

can someone help me solve this problem?

this my code,

```
new ListView(   padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 3.0),   children: <Widget>[
    new ListTile(
      title: new Text(
        "Day 1",
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.lightGreen, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'GoogleSans'),
      ),
      subtitle: new Stepper(
        currentStep: this._currentStep1,
        onStepTapped: (step){
          setState(() {
            this._currentStep1 = step;
          });
        },
        onStepContinue: (){
          setState(() {
            if(this._currentStep1 < 4){
              this._currentStep1 += 1;
            } else {
              //logika jika komplit
            }
          });
        },
        onStepCancel: (){
          setState(() {
            if(this._currentStep1 > 0){
              this._currentStep1 -= 1;
            } else {
              this._currentStep1 = 0;
            }
          });
        },
        steps: [
          Step(
              title: new Text("arrived in bali.",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'GoogleSans')),
              content: new Text("to register please show your QR code on the attendance menu. when it arrived at the venue to the admin.",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey,fontFamily: 'GoogleSans')),
              isActive: _currentStep1 >= 0
          ),
          Step(
              title: new Text("arrived in hotel bali.",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'GoogleSans')),
              content:  new Text("to book a room when it arrives at the hotel, show your QR code to the hotel admin to scan it.",style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey,fontFamily: 'GoogleSans')),
              isActive: _currentStep1 >= 2
          ),
          Step(
              title: new Text("Step 3"),
              content: new TextField(),
              isActive: _currentStep1 >= 3
          ),
          Step(
              title: new Text("Step 4"),
              content: new TextField(),
              isActive: _currentStep1 >= 4
          ),
          Step(
              title: new Text("Step 5 "),
              content: new TextField(),
              isActive: _currentStep1 >= 5
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),   ], ),
```

thank you for all the answers,
best regard.

Comment: What's the issue, seems to work for me. I'm able to scroll and also steps actions also work.

Comment: can you share your code, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Stepper](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) itself is already a scrollable widget.

If you want to place it in a [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), you can simply set `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` inside the `Stepper`.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Niklas,
the problem is I want my scroll to run and the stepper can be tappable,,
do you have other suggestions? or do I have to replace the list with different widget,?

Comment: Try setting `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` in the Stepper.

Comment: got it, I have found the answer, the answer is because my flutter is not updated. so the `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics ()` function does not exist. after I update, the code runs well, thanks @Niklas @Hemanth Raj,
best regard,